# Disabling the close button on a GLFW window

Tags: window, glfw

For my game using GLFW for windowing, I want to prohibit the user from closing the game window using the close button.  Is there any cross-platform way to do this?

Comment: For the record, I absolutely HATE any program that won't let me close or resize it. Many games do this and it really bothers me when I have to use their mouse to find out where their "close" button is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `glfwSetWindowCloseCallback` to set a callback that always returns `GL_FALSE`.

Answer (score 1):

You must add `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_DECORATED, GLFW_FALSE)` before `glfwCreateWindow()` call, this remove minimize, maximize, close button and borders, the window cannot be resized anymore.